# WPF Bing Maps control: mouse scroll stops working after setting properties

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, bing-maps

Before setting zoomLevel or center property I can use my mouse to move around the map(dragging) and zoom in/out using scroll wheel. After setting one of those, mouse scroll zoom in/out stops working. I tried to register my own mousewheelevent handler and it too stops working togather with built-in one. I also tried this:

```
        myMap.Center = center;
        myMap.ZoomLevel = zoomLevel;
        myMap.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(Map_MouseWheel);
```

But it didn't work. What's the problem here?

edit: tried also using 
    myMap.SetView(center,zoomLevel);

edit2: I'm using Integration.ElementHost to load WPF control in WinForms project. It gotta be something with that since with regular WPF project everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set focus to the map control
myMap.Focus()